# Visual Editor for Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a tool out there for visually building Django templates?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried it personally, but a co-worker uses the free [ActiveState Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) to edit Django templates, and the page I linked claims support for Django template editing.

There's also [netbeans-django](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316054658/https://code.google.com/p/netbeans-django/) that is building a Django plugin for Netbeans, but no idea how complete or how well it works.

I've read that TextMate has a "Django bundle" for editing code and templates if you're on a Mac.

Comment: But it is not visual (I mean: you can't see the final result and move fields on the page with a drag operation...)

Answer (score 5):

There is also [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Answer (score 2):

There's no WYSIWYG tool like Dreamweaver. But highligting is possible. I am using Kate to edit my templates.

For instance when you comment in Django template it inserts `{% comment %}`.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an oblique answer, but if being able to use tools like Dreamweaver on your templates is important to you, you may find you like Genshi better than Django Templates, and it's easy enough to switch your template engine.

Genshi is an XML templating language that is one of the inheritors of the Zope TAL family. Your template file *is* a valid XML file, so you can open it in any XML aware tool. Personally, once I got used to using XML templates, I couldn't go back, but they are slower to process ( an xml parser has to run behind the scenes ) and they require valid XHTML in your output which can be a good or a bad thing. ( Invalid user submitted html content for example would need to be forced clean using something like Beautiful Soup or ElementTree ).

Answer (score 1):

I'm really liking Eclipse with Pydev and the Aptana Studio 3 Eclipse plugin. More info here: http://pydev.blogspot.com/2010/08/django-templates-editor.html

(The first thing I did was change the theme. I quite like the Mac Classic theme's Django template highlighting.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget for the [Emacs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs) Users there is django template assistance. The Emacs link will take you to more helpful documentation in Emacs.